Limit of sum of linear combination of constants multiplied by different indicator functions
How would i even think about solving this limit? We have $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $a > 1$
$$
\lim_{ n \to \infty }  \sum_{i=1}^{n}i\mathbb{1}_{[i,i+1)}(x)-a\mathbb{1}_{[n,n+1)}(x)
$$

Ok, i understood that this whole function is just a fancy way of writing floor function for any $x \in \mathbb{R}^+$. The term with the $a$ at the end of the limit will disappear since the indicator function of it will require $x \in [\infty, \infty+1)$ where $[\infty, \infty+1) \cap \mathbb{R} = \emptyset$ so there is no such $x$.
